# WPF form to form update

Tags: wpf, forms, textbox

I am trying to update a label from one form to another. the code is compiling fine but not updating?

```
Class MainWindow 

    Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
        Dim frm As New Window1
        frm.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

second form:

```
Public Class Window1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        My.Windows.MainWindow.Label1.Content = "dsfdsfsdf"
        My.Windows.MainWindow.Label1.UpdateLayout()
    End Sub
End Class
```

it doesn't update the main form's label... hope that makes it clearer

Comment: Does it throw any exceptions or anything?

Comment: No it compiles and runs fine. no exceptions or any errors. i added a updatelayout() and still not changing. I must be doing something wrong. im trying to keep it as simple as possible

Comment: Try this: `Application.Current.MainWindow.Label1.Content = "whatever"`

Comment: closer. I can do a Application.Current.MainWindow = "test" but the label isn't working. Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you post the XAML and code behind for MainWindow?

Comment: <Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="Label" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="142,170,0,0" x:FieldModifier="Public" Name="Label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="186" />
    </Grid>
</Window>

Comment: I wrote a sample app that uses the code you've provided so far, and it works just fine.  You must be leaving something out, or you're missing something obvious.

Comment: well, yeah. When I type Application.Current.MainWindow. Label1 isn't an option in intellisense

Comment: You have to cast it to the appropriate class so I did: `((MainWindow)Application.MainWindow).Label1.Content = "testing"` (where the `(MainWindow)` is the class name for your main window).

Comment: Yes! Finally! TY very much! It shouldn't have been so tough *shakes fists at WPF. In Vb.Net it's
DirectCast(Application.Current.MainWindow, MainWindow).Label1.Content = "test"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's the code that you actually need:

Public Class Window1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    DirectCast(Application.Current.MainWindow, MainWindow).Label1.Content = "test"
End Sub
```

End Class

I'm not sure what the `My.Windows` collection is, but the `Application.MainWindow` gives you a reference to the window that is set as the start up object in the project properties (or the one you set in your app.xaml.cs file).  Previously you were probably getting a reference to a different instance of the `Window1` class, hence it was running and not throwing an exceptions, but since it wasn't the *actual* visible instance of the window then you didn't see any changes.